# IntelliJ IDEA Switch Statement Error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, switch-statement

**This question is not a duplicate because none of the fixes from the thread that this is a "duplicate" of worked for me.**

I am making a basic calculator program as my first Java program.  To do it I am using a switch statement to select the operator for the equation but when I try to run the switch statement I get a error:

> java: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.6 (use -source
>   7 or higher to enable strings in switch).

I have checked other answers but none of them seem to make sense in my situation.  I am using the Java 8 JDK and my project level is 8 which should be high enough to run this code.

My Code:

```
boolean pass = false;
    char sOP = 'n';

  while( pass == false) {

      System.out.print("Operator, +, -, *, or /: ");
      String op = scanner.nextLine();

      switch (op) {
          case "+":
              sOP = '+';
              pass = true;
              break;
          case "-":
              sOP = '-';
              pass = true;
              break;
          case "*":
              sOP = '*';
              pass = true;
              break;
          case "/":
              sOP = '/';
              pass = true;
              break;
          default:
              System.out.println("Invalid operator, please reenter.");
              pass = false;

      }
  }
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: This is not Intellij related. It could be any decent IDE and you'd get and equivalent error msg.

Comment: If you're certain you have everything correct then perhaps rebuilding or restarting will help. The error seems to suggest though that somewhere you're using 7.

Comment: Bneac, including a second question that is unrelated to the main question indicated by the error and title might not be a good idea as there's a high risk that people will miss it, and that answers will only target the first part of your question. For those reasons it would be better to ask the second part (about dynamic evaluation of expressions) as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a `switch` statement with `String` was not supported until Java 1.7. You should upgrade your version of Java.

Go to `Project Structure` -> `SDKs` and choose the correct Java SDK version.

Comment: I am using Java 8 though and that is the JDK that I have set up with IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @Bneac double check that the 1.8 SDK is the one that is selected in the project. `Project Structure` -> `SDKs`

Comment: I am using Java version 1.8.0_51.